# Must destructor be just available (public) or fully valid for default initialized class members?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, incomplete-type

Please consider a struct `A` having a field `u` of type `U<R>` with a default initializer. The destructor `~U<R>` is only declared:

```
template<typename T>
struct U {
    ~U();
};

struct R;

struct A {
    U<R> u = U<R>{};
};
```

All compilers accept this code, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oqMjTovMo

But if we define the destructor `~U<R>` as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct U {
    ~U() { static_assert( sizeof(T) > 0 ); }
};
```

then the current compilers diverge. MSVC keeps accepting the program, while GCC/Clang print the error

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'R'
```

demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/713TzPd6v

Obviously, the compiler must verify destructor availability of default initialing class members in case an exception occurs during construction. But does the standard require that the compiler just check the availability of the destructor (as MSVC does), or the compiler should verify its body as well? MSVC behavior looks more convenient here since it permits forward declaration of `R` by the moment of struct `A` definition.

P. S. This questing has not only purely theoretical interest. If one replaces `U` here with `std::unique_ptr` then it explains why class fields of type `std::unique_ptr<R>` are accepted by MSVC and rejected by GCC/Clang for incomplete classes `R`.

Comment: 1) I would add `int main() {}` to both example, as the first one errors because of missing `main`. 2) Can you give an example of _class fields of type `std::unique_ptr<R>` are accepted by MSVC and rejected by GCC/Clang for incomplete classes `R`_? [This works](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Po8rE8Ybn) for instance.

Comment: The destructor must be available/valid in the context where it's used. and this entirely depends on the places where you use the header. For `std::unique_ptr` headers you can use a forward declared type as a template parameter though assuming you're ok with defining a constructor/destructor and putting the implementation file as well as not using any other functionality that may use the destructor of the wrapped type in the header. E.g. header: `struct R; struct A{ A(); ~A(); std::unique_ptr<R> m_u;}` cpp file: `#include "R.hpp" A(){} ~A(){}`

Comment: It's not about the desctructor. It's about the inline code, which happens to be a destructor in this case, using `sizeof` on an incomplete type.

Comment: For (everyone's) reference: a related, but not the same, question is [How can adding code *after* the location of a compiler error fix the error when using unique_ptr for pimpl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68860276) One key difference is that the other question reports the same behavior for all three compilers (so not an answer to Enlico's second request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[dcl.init.aggr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.aggr#8): (emphasis mine)

> The destructor for each element of class type is ***potentially invoked*** ([class.dtor]) from the context where the aggregate initialization occurs.

[[basic.def.odr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#8):

> A destructor for a class is ***odr-used*** if it is potentially invoked.

[[basic.def.odr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#10):

> Every program shall contain exactly one **definition** of every non-inline function or variable that is **odr-used** in that program outside of a discarded statement; no diagnostic required.

So `~U()` is potentially invoked at `U<R> u` inside `A`, which requires its definition.

Then according to [[temp.inst]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#4):

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template is a declared specialization, the specialization of the member is implicitly ***instantiated*** when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist ...

Bonus note: and of course, it *is* actually [invoked](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.dtor#15) whenever an instance of `A` is destroyed. So it needs to be compiled.

Note: in the first version the compilers accept the code because the destructor is not inline, so it fails during linking ([example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rdjP8aPGx)).

As for MSVC accepting the code, it appears to be a bug.